# Sorting objects by the number of relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app to keep track of albums. The architecture is:

- Stream (albums list) `has_many` albums.
- Album `has_many` genres and streams.
- Genre `has_many` albums.

Doing:

```
Genre.left_joins(:albums).group(:id).order('COUNT(albums.id) DESC')
```

gives an array of genres sorted by the number of albums relations. If "Indie Rock" is the most popular genre, it will appear first in the array. This gives the most popular genres across all albums.

I want the counterpart for albums of a specific stream. Does someone have a precise operation to do this?

Comment: Looks like `Genre` also has many streams if you go via `Album` right? So just join the stream to query and then you can use soemthing like `where(:stream_name => 'Pop')` where `:stream_name` is column from streams table.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it works with `Genre.joins(:albums => :streams).group(:id).where("streams.name = ?", "2017").order('COUNT(albums.id) DESC')`